# Windows 10 app - SplitView or Pivot?

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, uwp

I create my first app for Windows 10. I will use the app for Windows 10 desktop  and phone. Great that one code will run on desktop and phone. In my old application for Windows Phone 8 I use  Panorama control with three tabs. But I can not decide which component to use - SplitView or Pivot? For desktop better suited SplitView . For phone better suited - Pivot. Need to choose one solution. What do you advise?

Comment: The *best* control is the right control for the **requirement**. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my old application for Windows Phone 8 I use  Panorama control with three tabs. Maybe there will be four tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your following statement is incorrect.

> For desktop better suited SplitView. For phone better suited - Pivot.

`SplitView` and `Pivot` are for different purposes -

`SplitView` consists of two parts - `Pane` and `Content`. The `Content` is where the main content goes. The `Pane` is really just a *drawer*. This control is meant to provide a very common *drawer navigation pattern* to the new UWP apps, similar to many iOS and Android apps.

Note that this control is also very flexible, you can use `AdaptiveTrigger` to customize its `DisplayMode` to completely hide the `Pane` when it's on a phone, and make it always visible when on a desktop machine.

Prior to UWP, the original *Metro Design* heavily relied on the `Panorama` control (i.e. the `Hub` control in UWP) for menu navigation and this later becomes a bit boring since almost all the apps that need a menu, use a `Pano`. So having a new `SplitView` will definitely help developers be a bit more creative on the main layout design. And besides, the *drawer navigation* is so widely used across other platforms and users generally know how to interact with it.

`Pivot` on the other hand, is simply a swipe-enabled *tab* control. It's meant to display information at the same level and should **never** be used like a navigation frame. Leave the navigation bit to the `SplitView` or the old *panorama* style `Hub` control, or whatever creative ways you can come up with.

So to answer your question, you don't have to choose one between them, these two controls can co-exist since one does the navigation and the other shows the information, just like what's in the picture below -
[image]

Comment: Thanks you. It is useful answer

Comment: @Justin  i create the same but my pivot header not clickable when i use both spilit and pivot control in same page, do you know the reason